# How to use an STL priority_queue + comparator with a specific constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, priority-queue, functor

I want to do this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <set>

class Comparator
{
   public:
   Comparator(SomeObject& rTool) : mrTools(rTool) {}

   bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
   {
      return mrTools.doSomething(a,b);
   }

   private:
   SomeObject& mrTools;
}

std::priority_queue<std::string, std::set<std::string>, Comparator> queue; 
//<- this doesn't compile
```

How can I initalize this queue providing Comparator with the reference it needs in the constructor ?

Answer (score 6):

You can provide an instance of `Comparator` to construct it; otherwise `Comparator()` will be used as the default argument to [constructor of `std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue), but `Comparator` doesn't have a default constructor. e.g.

```
SomeObject so;
std::priority_queue<std::string, std::set<std::string>, Comparator> queue(Comparator(so));
```

BTW: `std::set` doesn't satisfy the requirement of the underlying container of [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). You can use `std::vector` or `std::deque` instead.

> The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The
>   container must satisfy the requirements of [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), and its
>   iterators must satisfy the requirements of [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator).
>   Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual
>   semantics:
>
> - front()
> - push_back()
> - pop_back()
>
> The standard containers [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) satisfy these
>   requirements.

Comment: A `priority_queue` has less functionality than a `set` anyway. The only (but possibly very good) reason to prefer `priority_queue` is efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your `Comparator`, and everything to do with `std::set` not satisfying the requirements of [`SequenceContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer). You can use `vector` or `deque`, or write your own `SequenceContainer`, making sure to implement `front`, `push_back` and `pop_back`, and have `iterator`s that are `RandomAccessIterator`